Is there a way to make typescript infer a function argument type based on another argument type?
For example in a function like this:
function someFunc(err: Error | undefined, data: string | undefined) {
  if (err) throw err;
  data; // Intellisense should show `string`, not `string | undefined`
}

I tried this:
function someFunc<
  Err extends Error | undefined,
  Data extends Err extends Error ? undefined : string
>(err: Err, data: Data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  data.length; // 'data' is possibly 'undefined'
}

and this:
function someFunc(err: Error, data: undefined): void;
function someFunc(err: undefined, data: string): void;
function someFunc(err: Error | undefined, data: string | undefined) {
  if (err) throw err;
  data.length; // 'data' is possibly 'undefined'
}

Neither worked.
So the question is if it's even possible to do something like this, or should I just add another if check for data and move on?

Would it be an option for you to combine the two parameters err and data into a single parameter that takes a (tagged/discriminating) union type?

@balu Ah yes. I forgot about this one. It works and I might use it, but I would prefer separate args, if it was possible.

You can use a destructured discriminated union as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining or find a suitable duplication source; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz This actually works as I need! The only problem is when you call the function intellisense show these hints: someFunc(__0_0: Error, __0_1: undefined): void, someFunc(__0_0: undefined, __0_1: string): void. As you can see argument names don't look really pretty there. But I guess this is the closest thing to what I wanted.

You can label the tuples as shown in this playground link to get the intellisense you like. See the linked q/a for more info
